# Why does a standard error need to be boxed in main, but not an io error?

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, rust

Take the following code snippet:

```rust
fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    println!("Bonjour le Monde");
    Ok(())
}
```

This is perfectly fine code, but I wondered what would happen if I changed the type of the error to std::error::Error:

```rust
fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), std::error::Error> {
    println!("Bonjour le Monde");
    Ok(())
}
```

This is not good anymore:

> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

I fixed it like this:

```rust
fn main() -> std::result::Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("Bonjour le Monde");
    Ok(())
}
```

So why does the main function require Box<> for standard errors, but not for io errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::error::Error` is a trait included in the standard library. As Rust points out, it cannot determine how much memory will be need to store an `Error` at compiled time since a structure of any size could potentially be used. As such, you need to use some form of indirection, such as a reference, a pointer, or, in this case, a `Box`. See [TRPL Ch.17](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) for more information about using trait objects.

In contrast, `std::io::Error` is a structure from the `std::io` module (which also happens to implement `std::error::Error`). Rust *does* know large this structure is, so it can create a monomorphization of `Result` that uses it.

Comment: Great, this is very helpful. How does Rust know how large the std::io::Error structure is? Is it that io errors are bound by a specific upper byte size?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg All structures have a fixed size. If you take a look at the definition for [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/error.rs.html#56-58), you'll see that its comprised of just one member, which is the enum `Repr`. `Repr` itself is either 1) an `i32`, 2) a plain enum `SimpleError`, or 3) a `Box`, so the whole `io::Error` structure occupies size of the largest variant of `Repr` (likely `Box`), plus to some extra storage for the variant tag. On my system, it occupies `16` bytes due to alignment, but on a 32 bit system, it may only occupy `8` bytes.